# How can I unit test GC?

Tags: java, junit, garbage-collection, classloader

For a project, we need a way to run user scripts that can come with attached JAR files with additional classes.

What are my options when I want to write a couple of tests to make sure normal script don't leave anything dangling behind?

I specifically need to know: Are all classes from the attached JARs "unloaded"?

Note: I'm not looking for the 100% super-watertight solution that works across all versions of Java from 1.0 to 7. Right now, I just need to be better than "I have no idea".

Comment: Why would they be unloaded? Do you mean their instances will be GCed, i.e., the code and libraries of the user scripts don't have memory leaks? Are you loading them with a new class loader?

Comment: Yes. What I'd like is a way to ask the GC "could you GC this instance right now?" Or maybe "tell me how many references exist to instance `foo`" How do profilers do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The likely best option is to ensure your loaded jars are loaded by a specific class loader, and then to discard that class loader (after discarding all the objects).

As far as unit testing the unloading, if you go with this option, you need to extend your testing framework and customized class loaders to have a "create class loader on demand" flag.  Then you load the class once with the flag on, discard the class loader, and attempt to load the class again with the flag off.  If the class is truly not reachable, the second attempt should throw a class not found exception.  You then wrap your unit tests to pass if they fall into the exception, and fail if they succeed in hitting the line after the second load attempt.

If you are disposed to use more than pure-Java tools, an OSGi container might be a consideration.  Most of the established OSGi container implementations explicitly test class unloading.

Comment: +1 for the second option. To be 100% sure (which I know isn't the requirement), you would probably need to run the class loader with a security manager (to ensure that scripts didn't create threads, etc).

Comment: @Sean Reilly, Thanks.  The other options became noise, so I moved the message closer to the top.

Comment: The point of the question seems to be that Aaron is already doing what you describe in your first paragraph, but since you cannot explicitly discard Java objects he wants a way to check whether it's actually happening implicitly, or whether there is a leak.

Comment: @Michael Borgwardt, a custom class loader is responsible for constructing all objects, so it can have an awareness of all objects that are created (in it's domain).  Make those links weak references, call a garbage collection while shutting down the class loader, and if there are any still referenced Objects, the class loader can report it.  Still that's not unit testing; that sounds more like trying to push class loader design into the testing team.

Comment: @Edwin Buck: A classloader is responsible for construction objects? That's news to me. Admittedly I haven't written custom classloaders, but I don't see anything related to object construction in the API. And it has nothing to do with classloader design, more with not trusting user-supplied code not to contain classloader leaks and wanting a method to test for those.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt, I think you misunderstand.  A class loader is responsible for returning the Class Object, which is instrumental in constructing new objects.  If the class loader returns a delegating wrapper, it can get all the info it wants.

Comment: @Edwin: I like the idea to track all objects created by a classloader. Do you have some example code?

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt, sorry.  No code handy, but a start would be to set up a Map<Class, HashSet<Object>> to hold them all.  Then use something like ASM to add the "Object registration" into the class constructors to have the object check if it's being loaded by a "registering capable" loader at construction time, and if so, "register" itself.  Remember to use weak references in the "objects created from this classloader Map" or you will be in for one impressive memory leak!  I'll play with the idea at our LUG tonight.  Shouldn't be too hard to do, but slightly harder to get "right".

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't try to unit test this.  Instead, I'd run the JVM with -XX:-TraceClassUnloading and look to see if the classes in question show up in the trace output.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like what you want to test is that hose scripts don't have a [classloader leak](http://blogs.oracle.com/fkieviet/entry/classloader_leaks_the_dreaded_java).

To do that, I'd create a `WeakReference` to the `ClassLoader` used to load that JAR, then run the script, then call `System.gc()` and afterwards `assertNull(reference.get())`

Comment: an alternative could be to create an instance of URLClassLoader per JAR perhaps and use it to load the classes. Trash it (set to null) once done.

Comment: @aishwarya: that's not an "alternative" at all. You cannot "trash" java objects. Setting the reference to null only allows the object to be garbage collected if there are no other references. What I describe is how to test that the object *was* actually garbage collected. Classloaders are notoriously hard to get rid of because one reference to one object of any of the loaded classes hidden in a collection somwhere is enough to prevent the classloader and all the classes loaded through it from being garbage collected.

Answer (score 1):

This depends entirely on the way you allow the scripts to run.  Do they have access to the classes of the rest of the application?

The typical way to leak memory in Java is to have a static reference.  A static reference is only static within the ClassLoader of the class that contains it.  So, if you load your user scripts using a ClassLoader you manage yourself (and you should do this anyway), then the references (static or not) inside will be eligable for GC as soon as your classloader itself it.

The only way they could work around this, is to add a reference to one of their objects into one of yours.  So you have to be very careful with the API you expose.  Another way is if they would make a static reference to their class in a class from another ClassLoader.

I don't see a way to fully automate testing for this.  But I suppose you could trace the class unloading with any decent profiler.